# Displaying icons in AutoCompleteComboBox control

Tags: flex4

I have a `AutoCompleteComboBox` which list all the ports present in cards for a Network Element in String Format. I want to list the ports which are used in any service with a warning icon.

e.g:

```
Javed
Manoj
Shekhar
Riki
```

Suppose the String Javed & Shekhar is used in some service. So i need to display the AutoCompleteComboBox in the below format

```
 Javed (warning icon image)
 Manoj
 Shekhar (warning icon image)
 Riki
```